# How can I include an image in a Mailman footer?

Tags: mailman

I'd like the footer of a Mailman list to include an image. Is this possible? If yes, how?

I tried the obvious path of just typing `<img...>`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. For *extremely* good reasons, in Usenet it was enforced, and for email it is *strongly* recommended that the footer below the message is at the very most 4 lines, pure ASCII.

If you ask me, if I ever get into a mailing list sending out noise images that are several times larger than the message itself, I'll unsubscribe before I get the second message.

Comment: Well, the list is used all of once per week, and everyone on it is on a nice fat university internet connexion, so I suspect the tubes carrying our email will stand up to the increased pressure. Or should I just establish a minimum message length so it's always larger than the footer?

Comment: They never ever read their emails on a smart phone or other device with a smaller screen or thinner pipe? The thing about having a "minimum message length" I take as a rhetorical question, since adding unnecessary text is it's just as likely to get people to unsubscribe as adding unnecessary images.

Comment: This question can apply to more than just images. This answer is more of a comment.